# How to compare string.xml files's unicode character in android studio?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-xml-attribute

In my android project's string.xml file contains an unicode character.

```
<string name="percent">&#37;</string>
```

and MainActivity.java have this code :

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();

myString.append(getResources().getString(R.string.percent));

if(myString.substring(1).equals(getResources().getString(R.string.percent))){
 // do something
}
```

So my problem is that MainActivity.java code not comparing the unicode. How to solve this problem guys ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong overloaded `substring()` method :

`substring(1)` means *starting at position 1 (i.e. with 2nd character) to the end*.

You should use `substring(0, 1)` : *starting at position 0 (first character) and length 1*

`"%".substring(1)` : `""`

`"%".substring(0, 1)` : `"%"`